# Couldn't parse contents of <appname>_Prefix.pch: Unexpected character at line 1

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have started a project from an XCode template I have created.  When I try to run in debug mode it works fine; however, when I try to run it in release mode I get an error message

couldn't parse contents of _Prefix.pch: Unexpected character / at line 1

I haven't touched this file.  Any ideas on what has happened and how to fix it?

Comment: The symbol < and > in the error log message were interpreted as formatting code, and now the error display as "couldn't parse contents of _Prefix.pch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair pulling I came to the conclusion this was a result of something corrupted in the project.  I resolved this issue by creating a new blank project and re-importing all of my project files into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything strange at the beginning of the file when printing it in the terminal with the command cat configured to display non-printing characters?

`cat -v path_of_your_project/AppName_Prefix.pch`

What happens if you replace the file in your first project with the file from the new working project?

Can you edit your question and add the content of the file AppName_Prefix.pch?